# how to take a backup from server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I have connected to local and server database from local SqlServer 2005. How to take  a backup from server database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to setup a Maintenance Plan for your DB directly on the server that can have a DB backup performed on a defined schedule.  You could also create a backup with T-SQL as shown below.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDB] TO  DISK = N'C:\dbbackup.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'MyDB', SKIP, REWIND, 
NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```